# Connecting the RESET pin of AT8051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, reset

How should I connect the RESET pin in a microcontroller (AT8051), and why in that particular way?

Answer (score 5):

A fast [search on Google](http://images.google.com/search?q=8051+reset+circuit) gave me this:

[image]

The first circuit pulls the `RESET` pin low to enable the chip. The second circuit is the same, but with a reset button. If you press that, the chip will get reset.

Comment: Maybe add a normally reverse biased diode across the resistor; when power is shut-off the 5V collapses to 0V and there is a possibility the reset pin will see negative voltages due to charge on capacitor.

Comment: What about the ESD protection diodes that are almost surely already in the package?

Comment: How does the RESET work? Why to give a RESET pin & how does it auto RESET in fig.(1) ? What's the concept? RESET pin is reset just by giving a +5V. Then why that kind of circuit? Simple connect +5V to push btn switch & then to RESET pin. That's it. Isn't it?

Comment: Why the caps are used? And why the pull up & pull down?

Comment: @abhisekp when RESET is high, the device goes into "RESET mode", it doesn't do a thing until it gets out of this mode. So you'll have to get the device out of RESET, so you need to pull the pin down (with the resistor). Otherwise, the pin floats and you can't rely on the device getting out of RESET. The cap is added to make sure the device isn't reset due to EMI.

Comment: how is EMI in effect here?

Comment: @abhisekp if the power supply isn't stable, the cap makes sure a ripple won't cause a RESET.

Comment: @CamilStaps so had d power supply been stable, d cap is unnecessary?

Comment: @abhisekp in theory, I think so, I see many circuits without the cap. But it's good practice to use a cap, I'd recommend you to just add it in.

Answer (score 1):

When the 5V power is switched on, the capacitor shorts to 5V, and then gradually the RC circuit discharges to bring the reset pin to 0.

Calculate like this -

According to the 8051 documentation, the voltage across the reset pin should be at logic high for more than 2 machine cycles (where 1 machine cycle = 4 clock cycles). So \$V_i = 5.0V\$, \$V_f = 90\%\$ of \$V_i\$ (very safe). This means \$V_i \cdot e^{-t/RC} > V_f (= 0.9 V_i)\$.

So \$e^{-t/RC} > 0.9\$

so \$t/RC < -1 \cdot ln 0.9\$

now \$t = \dfrac{10}{f_{xtal}}\$ (safe, much higher than 2 machine cycles)

so \$ \dfrac{\frac{10}{f_{xtal}}}{RC} < 0.105\$

so \$ RC > \dfrac{10}{0.105 \cdot f_{xtal}}\$

so \$ RC > \dfrac{100}{f_{xtal}}\$

if \$ R = 10k \$,

\$C > \dfrac{100}{f_{xtal} \cdot 10k} \$

so \$ C > \dfrac{0.01}{f_{xtal}}\$, units of \$C\$ will be \$\mu F\$ if \$f_{xtal}\$ is in \$MHz\$.

Typically, if \$f_{xtal} = 11.0592MHz\$ so \$C > \dfrac{0.01}{11.0592} = 1nF\$. So any value of \$C > 1nF\$ and \$R = 10K\Omega\$ would do our job.

Comment: What does MFD (units of C) mean in your answer? Micro faradays? I've also formatted your equations using the site standard. Would you please make sure I didn't add any errors in it, please? Thanks.

Comment: MFD = micro farads. Please also add 1Machine Cycle = 4 clock cycles, and Vf = 0.9Vi (not 90 of Vi)

Comment: The formatting language had eliminated the % sign. I added it back. Sorry about that. What about the other changes? Is it all ok now?

Comment: Yes. I have already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

All this works if the reset pin has a hysteresis protection. If not we will need a supervisory chip.
Also, most reset pins are active low, so with the circuits shown above they will be in perennial reset mode. The resistor should be a pull up and not pull down. But my last point is not for the chip you mentioned in your doubt. Its more of a general comment.